# How to group by and aggregate on multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID     Balance     ATM_drawings    Value
 1      100         50              345 
 1      150         33              233
 2      100         100             333 
 2      100         100             234
```

I want data in that desired format

```
 ID     Balance_mean    Balance_sum     ATM_Drawings_mean    ATM_drawings_sum 
 1      75              250             41.5                 83 
 2      200             100             200                  100
```

I am using following command to do it in pandas

```
 df1= df[['Balance','ATM_drawings']].groupby('ID', as_index = False).agg(['mean', 'sum']).reset_index()
```

But, it does not give what I intended to get.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to specify aggregation functions for each series:

```
d = {'Balance': ['mean', 'sum'], 'ATM_drawings': ['mean', 'sum']}
res = df.groupby('ID').agg(d)

# flatten MultiIndex columns
res.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in res.columns.values]

print(res)

    Balance_mean  Balance_sum  ATM_drawings_mean  ATM_drawings_sum
ID                                                                
1            125          250               41.5                83
2            100          200              100.0               200
```

Or you can define `d` via `dict.fromkeys`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(('Balance', 'ATM_drawings'), ['mean', 'sum'])
```

Comment: How do I change the column names to the desired ones? It seems to be multiindex dataframe

Comment: I am able to do it with `credit_card_bal.groupby('ID', as_index = False).agg({'Balance':['sum','mean'],                                                                              'ATM_drawings':['sum','mean'], }).reset_index()`

Comment: Works perfectly,but I am getting `ID_` as a column how do I remove `_` from `ID` column?

Comment: As per my worked example, you shou'd get `ID_` if you don't `reset_index`. You can do this as a final step: `df = df.reset_index()`.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to achieve this using `agg`, but you could reuse the `groupby´ object to avoid having to do the operation multiple times, and then use transformations:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2],
    "Balance": [100, 150, 100, 100],
    "ATM_drawings": [50, 33, 100, 100],
    "Value": [345, 233, 333, 234]
})

gb = df.groupby("ID")
df["Balance_mean"] = gb["Balance"].transform("mean")
df["Balance_sum"] = gb["Balance"].transform("sum")
df["ATM_drawings_mean"] = gb["ATM_drawings"].transform("mean")
df["ATM_drawings_sum"] = gb["ATM_drawings"].transform("sum")
print df
```

Which yields:

```
   ID  Balance  Balance_mean  Balance_sum  ATM_drawings  ATM_drawings_mean  ATM_drawings_sum  Value
0   1      100           125          250            50               41.5                83    345
1   1      150           125          250            33               41.5                83    233
2   2      100           100          200           100              100.0               200    333
3   2      100           100          200           100              100.0               200    234
```