# How can I agg on multiple columns?

Tags: pandas

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I've researched this for a while and can't figure out how to do aggretations on multiple columns. This works:

```
df.groupby(['Exchange', 'Industry','Sector']).agg({'totalRevenue': ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

but instead of cycling through a for loop, I tried:

```
df.groupby(['Exchange', 'Industry','Sector']).agg({['totalRevenue', 'capitalExpenditures']: ['mean', 'min', 'max']})
```

I get: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

A related question around this is right now after I run the above command I run:

```
grouped_multiple.columns = ['totalRevenue_mean', 'totalRevenue_min', 'totalRevenue_max']
```

in order to name the new column names identifiable to me. How could I do that if I run the aggregation on multiple columns?

Comment: You can give `df.groupby(columns that need to be grouped).agg({'Balance': ['mean', 'sum'], 'ATM_drawings': ['mean', 'sum']})`  Are you looking to  aggregate on both values together?

Comment: Hi @JoeFerndz no not agg together(I assume I would have to put it in grouping otherwise) I just mean if I wanted to repeat the same agg on multiple columns with the same grouping, can I send it in one shot?

Comment: I got this link. see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653170/how-to-group-by-and-aggregate-on-multiple-columns-in-pandas/51653415#51653415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `fromkeys`

```
d = dict.fromkeys(['totalRevenue', 'capitalExpenditures'], ['mean', 'min', 'max'])
grouped_multiple = df.groupby(['Exchange', 'Industry','Sector']).agg(d)
```

For the column name

```
grouped_multiple.columns = grouped_multiple.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: wow! you are amazing, not only does it solve my problem but, in my opinion, it's written very beautifully. Thank you! It's tragic they don't give noble prizes for amazing SO answers...yet.